# Hex to dec/ dec to hex program. Cannot get program to print string for char array

Tags: c

I am writing a program that converts hex to dec and dec to hex. I have written two functions: itox(hexstring, n) and int xtoi(hexstring). These two functions are implemented by a driver. When I use printf to return the int and the hexstring, the hexstring never shows up in the output. Also, the program never seems to make it to the printf statement within the xtoi() function. This is the output I'm getting :

```
--------------:~/cs240/hw3$ gcc showxbits.c xbits.c -o showxbits
--------------:~/cs240/hw3$ ./showxbits
in itox, processing 47
                  47             0
```

I am new to C. Below is my code. Any advice is appreciated.

The driver code is:

```
  1 /*
  2  *  stub driver for functions to study integer-hex conversions
  3  *
  4  */
  5
  6 #include <stdio.h>
  7 #include "xbits.h"
  8
  9 #define ENOUGH_SPACE 100 /* not really enough space */
 10
 11 int main() {
 12   char hexstring[ENOUGH_SPACE];
 13   int m = 0, n = 47;
 14   itox( hexstring, n);
 15   printf("%s", hexstring);
 16
 17   /* for stub testing: create a fake input string*/
 18
 19   m= xtoi(hexstring);
 20
 21   printf("\t%12d %s %12d\n", n, hexstring, m);
 22
 23   return 0;  /* everything is just fine */
 24 }
 25
 26
```

The code for the two functions is :

```
  1 /*
  2  *  stubs for functions to study
  3  *  integer-hex conversions
  4  *
  5  */
  6
  7 #include <stdio.h>
  8 #include "xbits.h"
  9
 10 /* function represents the int n as a hexstring which it places in the
 11 hexstring array */
 12
 13 void itox( char hexstring[], int n) {
 14         char hexkey[] = {'0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', 'A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F'};
 15         int rem;
 16         int res = n;
 17         int i;
 18         for(i = 0; res < 16; i++){
 19                 rem = res%16;
 20                 res = res/16;
 21                 hexstring[i] = hexkey[rem];
 22         }
 23         i++;
 24         hexstring[i] = hexkey[res];
 25         i++;
 26         hexstring[i] = '\0';
 27
 28    printf("in itox, processing %d\t%s\n", n, hexstring);
 29 }
 30
 31 /* function converts hexstring array to equivalent integer value  */
 32
 33 int xtoi( char hexstring[]) {
 34         int cursor;
 35         int count = 0;
 36         char current;
 37         int dec = 0;
 38         int pow = 1;
 39         int i;
 40         int j;
 41         char hexkey[] = {'0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', 'A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F'};
 42
 43         for(cursor = (2*sizeof(char)); cursor >= 0; --cursor){
 44                 current = hexstring[cursor];
 45                 for(i = 0; i < 16; ++i){
 46                         if(current == hexkey[i]){
 47                                 if(count == 0){
 48                                         dec = dec + i;
 49                                 }
 50                                 else{
 51                                         for(j = 0; j < count; j++)
 52                                                 pow = pow * 16;
 53                                 dec = dec + pow*i;
 54                                 pow = 1;
 55                                 }
 56                         }
 57                 }
 58                 ++count;
 59         }
 60         return dec;
 61
 62   printf("in xtoi, processing %s\n", hexstring);
 63 }
 64
```

Comment: The value `0` is not the same as the character `'0'`. The value `0` is actually the string terminator.

Comment: There are also easier ways to construct strings from numbers: [`snprintf`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fprintf). And the opposite can be done by [`strtol`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strtol).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

missing single quotes

```
char hexkey[] = {'0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', 'A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F'};
                 ^ ^


 0=='\0' ==> Nul character used to terminate strings.

 0!='0'    

'0' ASCII value 48
```

---

Here you are going wrong

```
for(i = 0; res < 16; i++){     
               ^ 
                  rem = res%16;
                  res = res/16;
                 hexstring[i] = hexkey[rem];
         }
```

for loop condition wrong.

```
   n==47 ==> res==47 and res<16 ==> 47 < 16 failed.
```

---

Modify Like this

```
for(i = 0; res >0; i++)
         {
                  rem = res%16;
                  res = res/16;
                  hexstring[i] = hexkey[rem];
         }
                   hexstring[i] = '\0';

 printf("in itox, processing %d==%s\n", n, hexstring); // You need to reverse it.
```

Comment: I'm sorry I'm confused by your comment. If I understand it correctly, are you saying the character for zero == '\0' (I thought '\0' was used to terminate a string) and not 0 == '0'?

Comment: Okay so my issue is that when I call for hexstring the program thinks the string is immediately terminated?

Comment: I knew that was an issue and have changed it.... I was still getting no output for hexstring even when this wasnt present in the program.

Comment: yeah just ran it again with the single quotes changed back. Same output :(

Comment: That is without a doubt an error. Now I'm getting 
in itox, processing 47  2
2                 47 2          527
 for output.... so the 2 is the output for hexstring

Comment: @Gangadhar thank you that fixed it! now just to figure out why my other function isn't outputting anything -_- ... Thank you again for your help!

Answer (score 0):

I don't have enough rep to comment.  This post helped me out a lot.  If anyone else comes across this the issue for why his second function won't print is that his return statement is before his printf statement.  If here were to flip them around:

```
  printf("in xtoi, processing %s\n", hexstring);
  return dec;
```

Then the second function will print the line.